# "‘string’ undeclared" in code from "Basic Graphics Programming With The XCB Library"

Tags: c, string, x11, xcb

Here was the code that caused the problem:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_atom.h>

int main ()
{
  xcb_connection_t *c;
  xcb_screen_t     *screen;
  xcb_window_t      win;
  char             *title = "Hello World !";
  char             *title_icon = "Hello World ! (iconified)";



  /* Open the connection to the X server */
  c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

  /* Get the first screen */
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

  /* Ask for our window's Id */
  win = xcb_generate_id (c);

  /* Create the window */
  xcb_create_window (c,                             /* Connection          */
                     0,                             /* depth               */
                     win,                           /* window Id           */
                     screen->root,                  /* parent window       */
                     0, 0,                          /* x, y                */
                     250, 150,                      /* width, height       */
                     10,                            /* border_width        */
                     XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, /* class               */
                     screen->root_visual,           /* visual              */
                     0, NULL);                      /* masks, not used     */

  /* Set the title of the window */
  xcb_change_property (c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, win,
                       WM_NAME, STRING, 8,
                       strlen (title), title);

  /* fixed it by replacing WM_NAME with XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME
  and replacing STRING with XCB_ATOM_STRING */

  /* Set the title of the window icon */
  xcb_change_property (c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, win,
                       WM_ICON_NAME, STRING, 8,
                       strlen(title_icon), title_icon);

  /* fixed this by replacing WM_ICON_NAME with XCB_ATOM_ICON_NAME
  and replacing STRING with XCB_ATOM_STRING */

  /* Map the window on the screen */
  xcb_map_window (c, win);

  xcb_flush (c);

  while (1) {}

  return 0;
}
```

gcc generated an error because WM_NAME and WM_ICON_NAME weren't defined anywhere; XCB_ATOM_ should have been prepended. I found that solution from reading forum posts online, and from reading xproto.h

However, STRING doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. I searched string.h. The only cases in which STRING was found were in comments. I tried changing STRING to string, but it still wouldn't compile.

```
$ gcc -Wall -o win-icon-name win-icon-name.c -lxcb
win-icon-name.c: In function ‘main’:
win-icon-name.c:40:42: error: ‘string’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                        XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, string, 8,
                                          ^
win-icon-name.c:40:42: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I solved the problem by putting "XCB_ATOM_" before "STRING", and it compiled just fine.

Comment: The code in question should be posted here directly - the tutorial may change and render your question invalid.  Asking a question on SO about the code is valid; asking for a better tutorial is not.

Comment: The tutorial index link 13.2 actually goes to 12.2 (which appears to be the code you are referring to in any case).  Another reason why you should post the code rather than referencing an off-site resource.

Comment: @sOs : In which case perhaps your answer is perhaps and answer after all, but it is not at all clear that you have resolved the issue - you should at least make that clear and even accept your own answer.  It sees to me however that your problem was probably the use of `string` rather then `STRING`; you clearly did not copy & paste it at all!

Comment: @Clifford, I have edited my code, so that's why it doesn't appear at the code on the page I linked to. I even said that I changed the case of "STRING", trying to see if that helped. XCB_ATOM_STRING is what it should be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would now do better to add an answer with an actual code fragment showing the fix rather than just *describing* the fix, because in the context of the error message text, it is not at all clear when you mean.  And you shouldn't add the answer to the question in any case - no one who needs it will look for it there.

Comment: As it seems to be an error in the tutorial, it may be worth mentioning the tutorial by name in the title to enable others with the same problem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clifford suggested, here is a separate post with the fixed code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_atom.h>

int main ()
{
  xcb_connection_t *c;
  xcb_screen_t     *screen;
  xcb_window_t      win;
  char             *title = "Hello World !";
  char             *title_icon = "Hello World ! (iconified)";



  /* Open the connection to the X server */
  c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

  /* Get the first screen */
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

  /* Ask for our window's Id */
  win = xcb_generate_id (c);

  /* Create the window */
  xcb_create_window (c,                             /* Connection          */
                     0,                             /* depth               */
                     win,                           /* window Id           */
                     screen->root,                  /* parent window       */
                     0, 0,                          /* x, y                */
                     250, 150,                      /* width, height       */
                     10,                            /* border_width        */
                     XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, /* class               */
                     screen->root_visual,           /* visual              */
                     0, NULL);                      /* masks, not used     */

  /* Set the title of the window */
  xcb_change_property (c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, win,
                       XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 8,
                       strlen (title), title);

  /* Set the title of the window icon */
  xcb_change_property (c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, win,
                       XCB_ATOM_WM_ICON_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 8,
                       strlen(title_icon), title_icon);

  /* Map the window on the screen */
  xcb_map_window (c, win);

  xcb_flush (c);

  while (1) {}

  return 0;
}
```